# ValueProvider.GetValue giving exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am reading the book "Programming Microsoft ASP.Net MVC" third edition by Dino Esposito. I am trying to run the below example.

```
public ActionResult Echo()
    {
        var data = ValueProvider.GetValue("data").AttemptedValue ?? (ValueProvider.GetValue("today").AttemptedValue ?? String.Empty);    
        return View();
    }
```

I added the route config as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "EchoRoute",
            url: "echo/{data}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Echo", data = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```

Now if I try with a url with a parameter like localhost/echo/myName, the code works, but if I put in a query string like localhost/echo?today=02/24/2016 I get exception as below:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKF9E.png)

Not sure what exactly is happening here.

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Copy (or write manually) error mesage as text.

Comment: Use a short-circuit to ensure objects that are null are checked first: The null conditional operator: ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have marked `{data}` as optional. And you have not provided a value for `{data}` in your example URL `/echo?today=02/24/2016`. So, the value for `ValueProvider.GetValue("data")` is `null`. You need to check whether it is `null` before attempting to call `.AttemptedValue`.

You need to do the same for `today` since query string values are also optional.

```
var data = ValueProvider.GetValue("data") != null ? 
    ValueProvider.GetValue("data").AttemptedValue : 
        (ValueProvider.GetValue("today") != null ?
        ValueProvider.GetValue("today").AttemptedValue : 
        String.Empty);
```

Although, you could probably use some `if` statements to make the code more readable than this.

Comment: This. Except I would personally prefer this way: var data = ValueProvider?.GetValue("data")?.AttemptedValue ?? String.Empty;